# How to detect update in a django admin form validator

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I have a custom validator for a field in the `Post` model to be used
in the admin interface, the purpose of the validator is to verify
that no other post has the same `url` and `category`, but **I can't find
the way to distinguish from an update or a new `Post`**; which in the case
of an update it'll be no problem with the existence of a `post` with
the same url and category.

Here is the validator:

```
class MyPostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post

    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']        
         # if doesn't have any category then 
         # just return the url to handle the error.
        try:
            cat = self.cleaned_data['category']
        except KeyError:
            return url

        if UPDATE: #  UPDATE???
            #DON'T  COMPLAIN IF IS THE SAME, RETURN THE URL
            return url
        else: # IS NEW!
            try:
                Post.objects.get(category=cat, url=url)
            except Post.DoesNotExist:
                return url
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Already exists post with category "%s" and url "%s"'%(cat, url))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to do this: if you set `unique_together` in your model's Meta class, the admin will automatically validate that no other instance exists with the same combination.

However, to answer the general question, the way to tell if this is an update is to check that `self.instance` exists and has a value for the `pk` field.

```
if hasattr(self, 'instance') and self.instance.pk is not None:
    #update
else:
    #new
```